# Comparing Strings Not Working - Really Weird

Tags: iphone, xcode, ios6

For whatever reason, I can't seem to figure out what I can't get my code to properly compare two strings. I have an array of objects (profiles that contain a string: group) and I simply want to remove this profile object if its group does not match a string.

This is what I have:

The Profile object .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *group;
```

A controller file that is looking through the array and dumping out the incorrect profiles - its .h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *buttonSelected;
```

This *buttonSelected is set when the user selected a button the code simply checks the sender tag and assigns the appropriate string like so:

```
[controller setbuttonSelected:@"My Button Has Been Selected"];
```

The problem comes when when I attempt the compare this buttonSelected and the array object - which is a profile object with a group property:

```
_profileArray = [xmlParser profiles];

for(int i=0; i<[_profileArray count]; i++){
  NSLog(@"Comparing button: %@ and group: %@", [self buttonSelected], [[_profileArray objectAtIndex:i] group]);

  if([[self buttonSelected] isEqualToString:[[_profileArray objectAtIndex:i] group]]) NSLog(@"Equal");
}
```

The _profileArray has 3 objects, with only two of those whose group is actually equal to buttonSelected. So I should only have the system output 2 "Equal", however it never outputs "Equal".

Comment: try using one of the 'compare' methods as isEqualToString compares also unicode characters (As I do not know how you fill up your string it might be the problem)

Comment: I glad you brought this up as when the app reads in an XML file is does add a bunch of crap to the string - I haven't figured out why - but I do go through and clean this up and reset the "clean" data back to the object. I had left out group so I went back and added this. I still have the same problem though.

Comment: It does seem as though even after cleaning the Profile properties by doing this:

NSString *cleanGroup = [[_profileArray group] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];

that the profile information still has \n and a bunch of whitespace in it. Why would this continue being like this?

Comment: In your log line, you should check the string lengths to see if you're running into hidden characters or spaces.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you start by breaking your code in more easily debuggable parts and then step through it. I would do something like this.

```
NSString *buttonSelectedToCompareAgainst = [self buttonSelected];
NSLog(@"button selected was: %@", buttonSelectedToCompareAgainst);

NSString *profileGroupString;
NSComparisonResult compareResult;
for(Profile *profile in _profileArray){
 NSLog(@"Checking profile: %@", profile);

 profileGroupString = [profile group];
 NSLog(@"Checking profile group: %@", profileGroupString);

 compareResult = [buttonSelectedToCompareAgainst caseInsensitiveCompare:profileGroupString];

 NSLog(@"compare result: %d", compareResult);
}
```

Comment: The compareResult comes back as 1 - though I can't find what this means exactly.

Comment: It means the other string is "bigger" than the compared string. Check for NSComparisonResult here : https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSComparisonResult

Answer (score 0):

Got it figured out. I was cleaning the whitespaces etc. from a different array instead of the one I was using to compare the strings, thus the comparisons were never coming out like they should. After cleaning the array I was using everything worked fine.